# How to compile a library and then use it with ITK

Tags: c++, xml, cmake, itk

I want to use TinyXml in my ITK project

Here is a typical CMakeLists.txt that I use when I am working exclusively on ITK

```
project( cl02johnsonhj )
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

find_package ( ITK REQUIRED )
include( ${USE_ITK_FILE} )

add_executable( IteratorTests IteratorTests.cxx )

target_link_libraries( IteratorTests ${ITK_LIBRARIES} )
```

So this project has IteratorTests.cxx

However, I want to use a xml parser for my project and our group currently uses TinyXML2. 
When I downloaded from github, it has two files namely tinyxml2.cpp and tinyxml2.h.

My question is how do I compile those two files(tinyxml2.cpp and tinyxml2.h) within my frame work, and use it as tinyxml library in my itk project? I am very new to cmake and how to make it work. I have been trying and so far no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Probably, the simplest way is to replace

```
add_executable( IteratorTests IteratorTests.cxx )
```

with

```
add_executable( IteratorTests IteratorTests.cxx tinyxml2.cpp )
```

assuming that you have `tinyxml2.cpp` and `tinyxml2.h` right beside your own source files.

You also can make a separate library, but perhaps it's better to leave this exercise for the next time :)